# Facebook does not redirect to callback URL after user logins

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Im having an app which allows user connect to his facebook account.
If the user facebook is already logged in there is no issue with it but if facebook has not been logged in yet the app redirect it to the facebook login page, after user logs in, it redirect to facebook home page instead of call back url.

Here is the generated call back url by PHP:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=af0be0925ecf8bc7348c06c23bacaac9&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.3.1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Finsights.app%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email%2Cread_insights%2Cmanage_pages%2Cpublic_profile%2Cads_read%2C+ads_management
```

In addition to above scenario, when the user is already logged in to facebook but has not used my app and the app trying to get facebook's permission it happens and redirect to facebook home page instead of call back url.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to check if the user is authorized in the callback URL script and only the redirect to the home page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but problem is it never backs to my home page, it returns to Facebook.com which i can not do anything there. Perhaps the problem is the call back URL, maybe a parameter is missed there.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide the URL of a page that exhibits this behavior. Can you do that?